# Does PySide support Python 3?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

The reason I ask this is because I have seen [this page](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Python_3_Support) but I can't find the Mac OSX binaries to download from the downloads page. Is there a special place to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They wrote:

An investigation about Python 3 support has been made. According to the investigation, there are no insurmountable obstacles for Python 3 support.

https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Roadmap

https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Python_3_Issues

Comment: I have seen that but if you go to the link in my OP you will see that the first sentence says `PySide has included support for Python 3.2 since version 1.0.8`. If this is true where can I get those binaries?

Comment: @edhedges I think you have to build it by yourself

Answer (score 15):

This question is old, but is one of the first answers on google, so worth nothing:

- Pyside has a python 3 subdir and should work with Python 3
- Last release is August 2013
- The official repository is gitorius, not github (github is an out of date copy)

Comment: Thanks! I think this is good info since it's been a while since this was asked.

Answer (score 5):

Without having it tested myself, but on the qt project site it is [stated](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Python_3_Support):

> PySide has included support for Python 3.2 since version 1.0.8. If there are any issues with Python 3 support, they should be reported in [the Qt Project bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/).

With a 'last modified' date back in June, 2016

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here [Installing pyside with python3 on os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799514/installing-pyside-with-python3-on-os-x)

Long story short, the answer is yes and it can be installed with hombrew. However, PySide has a somewhat unkown future. From what I can tell there is no active development on PySide, and it may be time to use PyQt which is actually slightly easier to install.

Comment: If this is this case, it's unfortunate.  PyQt's licensing is much more restrictive.