# Installing pyside with python3 on os x

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyside, homebrew

I have tried to install pyside together with python3 on osx mountain lion.
I have been trying both

```
brew install pyside
```

But then it only works in python2.

I have also tried using the buildscripts from the pyside github rep. Making the changes needed

```
./build_and_install
```

fails however, with

```
Linking CXX shared library libpyside.cpython-33m.dylib
[  4%] Built target pyside
[  4%] Running generator for QtCore...
/bin/sh: /Users/einar/devel/pkg/pyside-sandbox-python3/bin/SHIBOKEN_GENERATOR-NOTFOUND: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [PySide/QtCore/PySide/QtCore/qabstracteventdispatcher_wrapper.cpp] Error 127
make[1]: *** [PySide/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know what to do now. I found this page [pyside forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22978) suggesting that I only have to symlink some stuff to get it working in python3 after doing `brew install pyside` but `/usr/local/Cellar/pyside/1.1.2/lib` only has files named 2.7 something.

Has anyone managed to get pyside working with python3 on osx or know of some guide on how to do it? My google-fu is failing me.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I [feel your pain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159722/pip-install-pyside-fails-qtcore-framework-check-os-x "pip install PySide fails QtCore Framework check (OS X)"), though I'm having separate issues (not using homebrew, QtCore link problems, etc.).

Comment: @ChrisKrycho No, not yet, but there are people working on it I think https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16439

Comment: that's good to know. I've been thinking about trying homebrew for a while, but things like this have kept me away so far.

Comment: @ChrisKrycho it's pretty good for many other things. And you can allways choose what you want to manage with it, and do the rest manually.

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed in Homebrew ([see wiki](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python)).  Installing Pyside with

```
brew install pyside --with-python3
```

will install it for both Python 2 and Python 3.  For this to work, you may have to uninstall `shiboken` and `pyside` first if they were already installed for Python 2.

Comment: N.b. This is broken again as of early 2014. The homebrew recipe no longer supports the `--with-python3` option, though I am hoping someone will add in back in sooner rather than later (possibly I will be able to do it sometime in the next month).

Comment: Further update: as of [this pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/27504) (which should be in the release shortly), this works again. I didn't do it, but I'm very grateful to the fellow who did.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in this case not use homebrew, and do a

```
pip3 install pyside
```

? Assuming you have brewed python3.

Edit: Does not work. That is probably the reason a homebrew formula exists for it..

Comment: Even if you _haven't_ brewed python3, this is generally the way to go. The Homebrew docs explain that you should use `pip` for Python packages whenever possible, not `brew`. And this is _more_ true for non-Homebrew Python than for Homebrew Python. Unfortunately, there are a few packages that don't build cleanly with `pip`—and, for obvious reasons, those are generally the ones that `brew` has packages for in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning you can use homebrew with some small modifications

1. brew edit pyside
2. Modify which_python to return simply "python3.3" (or whatever version you are using)
3. Add the CMAKE flag -DUSE_PYTHON3=1
4. Save and Exit
5. brew edit shiboken
6. Modify python_prefix to be `python3.3-config --prefix`
7. Modify python_version to be `python3.3-config --libs`
8. Modify which_python to return "python3.3"
9. brew uninstall pyside shiboken
10. brew install pyside
11. python3 -c "from PySide.QtGui import *"
12. Bask in Glory.

Note! This may cause conflicts if pyside is installed for python2 as well. There is active development on this issue for both pyside and pyqt. See https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/18588